# "use Harry as example" vs. "use Harry as the example" vs. "use Harry as an example"

Tags: grammar

Alice asks Michael an English grammar question. Michael is trying to give an example to explain that, so Michael says

> let's use Harry **as example**
>
> let's use Harry **as the example**
>
> let's use Harry **as an example**

which one should Michael use?

As far as I know, the first one might be incorrect, as "example" is a countable noun, the speak should use an article. Is my understanding right? How about others?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are correct about the first - this does not sound grammatically correct.

*Let's use Harry as an example* is correct. Michael might then want to take someone else to use as another example.

*Let's use Harry as ***the*** example* implies, probably incorrectly, that there is one and only one example.  The one and only example that exists uses Harry to demonstrate it.
In reality there would be countless examples of correct grammar therefore let's use Harry as *an* example and if Alice still doesn't get it we might ask Harry if he doesn't mind role playing another example of the point being made.

Comment: Both ...as an example, and ...as the example should work, depending on the context. "let's use Harry as the example" points to a context that 'Harry' as an example is being talked about, or is familiar to the teller, whereas ...as an example seems to say ...'one among many examples.

Comment: Further to @RamPillai's comment, there could be one and only one example _that we are using now,_ in which case the definite article would be correct (as would the indefinite article; either is acceptable).  This is analogous to a sentence such as "give me the fork."  There may be several identical forks present, but if a specific fork is intended, the definite article is indicated.  More closely analogous: "we need a tool; let's use this screwdriver as the tool."  The problem with single sentence questions such as this is that there isn't enough context to identify a unique correct answer.